# Strange deformation when changing Vector3 of the Mesh vertices

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I have strange situation, when I am trying to deform some mesh.

I have scene with two object - lower smaller cylinder (deformer) and upper bigger cylinder (deformable).

Both objects has C# scripts:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class deformer : MonoBehaviour
{

    bool clicked = false;
    public float speed = 2f;
    public Mesh mesh;
    public Vector3[] verts;
    public float maxDistance;
    public GameObject explosion;

    void Start ()
    {
        mesh = this.GetComponent<MeshFilter> ().mesh;
        verts = mesh.vertices;
        this.GetComponent<MeshFilter> ().mesh = mesh;
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter (Collision other)
    {
        Debug.Log ("Collided with " + other.gameObject.name);
        if (other.gameObject.GetComponent<deformable> () != null) {
            Vector3 colPosition = transform.InverseTransformPoint (other.contacts [0].point);
            movePoints (other.gameObject);
        }
    }

    public void movePoints (GameObject other)
    {

        print ("entering movePoints");
        Vector3[] otherVerts = other.GetComponent<deformable> ().verts;
        float distance;
        for (int i=0; i<otherVerts.Length; i+=1) {
//          print(i);

            distance = Vector3.Distance ((GetComponent<Rigidbody> ().position), other.transform.TransformPoint (otherVerts [i]));

            if (distance <= maxDistance) {

                print (otherVerts [i]);                     
                otherVerts [i] = new Vector3 (otherVerts [i].x, otherVerts [i].y + (1 / distance), otherVerts [i].z);

            }
        }
        other.GetComponent<deformable> ().UpdateMesh (otherVerts);
    }

}
```

and

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class deformable : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Mesh mesh;
    public Vector3[] verts;
    public Mesh oldMesh;

    void Start ()
    {
        if (mesh == null) {
            oldMesh = mesh = this.GetComponent<MeshFilter> ().mesh;
        }
        verts = mesh.vertices;
        this.GetComponent<MeshFilter> ().mesh = mesh;
    }

    public void UpdateMesh ()
    {
        mesh.vertices = verts;
        this.GetComponent<MeshFilter> ().mesh.vertices = mesh.vertices;
    }

    public void UpdateMesh (Vector3[] points)
    {
        mesh.vertices = points;
        this.GetComponent<MeshFilter> ().mesh.vertices = mesh.vertices;
        this.GetComponent<MeshCollider> ().sharedMesh = null;
        this.GetComponent<MeshCollider> ().sharedMesh = mesh;
    }

    void OnApplicationQuit ()
    {
        this.GetComponent<MeshFilter> ().mesh.vertices = oldMesh.vertices;
        this.GetComponent<MeshCollider> ().sharedMesh = null;
        this.GetComponent<MeshCollider> ().sharedMesh = oldMesh;
    }

}
```

As result, when deformer hits deformable, no changes applied to the deformable object:

Initial scene:
[image]

Hit scene:
[image]

After hit scene - here deformable MUST be changed:
[image]

And strangest in this situation is fact, what changes of the script doesn';t applied on Game scene, but applied on the Scene of the Unity editor!
[image]

Why changes doesn't applied on the game scene, but applied on the Editor scene?

Comment: Have you tried instantiating a copy instead of modifying the original mesh?

Comment: Also, have you tried marking the mesh as dynamic?

Comment: No, I haven't try to instantiate object... Now I trying to change code like `public class deformable : MonoBehaviour {
 
 public Mesh mesh;
 public Vector3[] verts;
 public Mesh oldMesh;
 
 void Start () {
  if (mesh == null) {

   oldMesh = mesh = this.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh;
  }

  mesh.MarkDynamic (); ` but it not helped for me...

Comment: You still don't use `UnityEngine.Object.Instantiate` method.

Comment: Have you Skype or GTalk (Google) account? :) Can we discuss it in chat?